# How to enter "expert mode" on CheckPoint firewall using netmiko?

Tags: python, firewall, checkpoint, netmiko

I'm trying to connect to CheckPoint firewall using netmiko and by default I'm getting the "clish mode".

The problem is that when I'm trying to enter "expert mode" by .send_command_timing() I'm not able to enter the "expert mode" password in the current field but only as a command on the clish mode.

I would like to get some ideas for optional ways to enter "expert mode" using netmiko.

I could'nt find any information for that anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a bash admin account to get into Expert mode right away.